# Is that safe to use kfifo (not a _spinlock flavour) in fiq/nmi handlers?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

Basically need to pass variable-size records to and from FIQ handler (ARM platform).

During any get/put operation on **kfifo** (on the user-space/kernel side only) I am going to disable all IRQs and preemption.

Is that a safe way to use **kfifo** in Linux?